# Java - method equals and more possible letters

Tags: java, equals

I am doing a cipher program, so I am replacing letters with other letters.
Here comes my problem:
I need to replace ONLY letter, not special symbols so I am checking if selected character is letter or not. I need to use equals method with more possible letters to get "true"
I have:

```
if(pismenka[i].equals(["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]))
```

but it doesn't work at all, it was only idea. Do I have to use || symbol or there is any more clear solution?

Thank you, AliFox.

Comment: The `isLetter` method of the `Character` class might be a good option for you.

Comment: It should be `"[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]"` and not `["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]`.

Comment: Thanks Chief Two Pencils,

if(pismenka[i].equals("[a-z]"))

works perfectly!

Comment: Sorry, but "It doesn't" is saying nothing to me, please can you extend your answer? Actually it works. Of course, that I have to write "[a-z|A-Z]", but I have lowercased that text :)

Comment: `equals` wouldn't respect that regular expression.  It doesn't accept a regex as its argument.  `equals` only takes `Object` as a parameter, and if the two objects weren't content-equivalent, then your equals expression would never work.

Comment: If it appears to be working, then it's for some other reason - not because of `if(pismenka[i].equals("[a-z]"))`.

Comment: if(!pismenka[i].equals("[a-z]")){pr=pismenka[i];}
  I have this in my code and after that "else if" and the whole coding program. And it's running, so it's working. Matches perfectly my problem. It's coding only letters

Comment: `matches` is **not** `equals`.  Just FYI.

Comment: Right.  I give up.  It works perfectly, provided you don't put it in your code.

Comment: Of course, that I'll use matches method, if its more clear. Just saying, that equals works too.

Comment: That #matches([a-z]) will compile the regular expression each time it is invoked. You chipher program will suffer from this.

Comment: hnnng, so what's better to use?

Comment: see my earlier answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For identifying characters you can use the following ([Java Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29)):

```
Character.isLetter(<target_char>)
```

And if replacement is to be done, following would help you replace characters from a-z:

```
<target_string>.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]",<replacement>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the String's `replaceAll` method, that takes a regex as a first argument.

Assuming you want to replace all non-special characters with a String `replacement`, the command would be:

```
pismenka[i].replaceAll("[a-z]",replacement);
```

Then, you don't need another explicit check if your String matches the regex. It is done inside this method. If your String does not contain any non-special characters, it is left intact.

Comment: But I dont want to replace anything, I just want to check if it's a letter or not. Get "true" or "false"

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you wanted to replace them, since you are saying " I need to replace ONLY letter". This replaces the letters, without the need for another explicit check...

Answer (score 0):

Character#equals(Object) checks whether or not your character is equal to the array (not to any its element). They are obviously not equal.
If you need to check that your character is a lower-case latin then use this check

```
c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'.
```